# Prove that the following collection of subsets of $\Bbb R$ is a topology?

Tags: general-topology

a. $T_1$ consists of $\Bbb R, \emptyset$ and every interval $(-n,n)$, for $n$ any positive integer.

b. $T_2$ consists of $\Bbb R, \emptyset$ and every interval $[-n,n]$, for $n$ any positive integer.

c. $T_3$ consist of $\Bbb R, \emptyset$ and every interval $[n, \infty )$, for $n$ any positive integer.

I think all of them are topologies of $\Bbb R$, but I am not sure. Please help me and explain your answers. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: You know that a set $\mathcal{T} \subset \mathfrak{P}(\mathbb{R})$ is a topology iff $\mathbb{R}\in\mathcal{T}, \varnothing \in \mathcal{T}$, and $(\forall U, V \in \mathcal{T}) (U\cap V \in \mathcal{T})$, and $(\forall \{U_i : i \in I\} \subset \mathcal{T}) (\bigcup\limits_{i\in I} U_i \in \mathcal{T})$. Check these conditions for your $T_1, T_2, T_3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A family $T$ of subsets of the real line (really, any set, but let's stick with the real line for the purpose of this answer) is a topology if all these three hold:

1. $\Bbb R$ and $\emptyset$ are members of the family.
2. Any union of members of the family $T$ is a member of $T$.
3. Any finite intersection of members of $T$ (alternatively: "any intersection of two members of $T$") is also a member of $T$.

Property 1 is easy to check, because the problem tells you right away that it is fulfilled.

Property 3 is not so difficult to confirm / reject either, just take a few members from whatever $T$ you're working with and see what their intersection turns out to be. See if you can spot a pattern, and try to argue why this pattern must hold for the intersection of *any* finite collection of members of $T$ (alternatively any *pair* of members).

Now, for property $2$ you need to be a bit careful, because now we might be handling infinitely many members. Therefore you need to break it up into two cases, depending on whether there is a largest $n$, or if there is always a larger *n* for the specific collection of members. Still, in each case, the procedure is more or less like for property $3$ above.