# Showing collection of subsets of R is a topology

Tags: general-topology

Show that the collection of subsets of $\Bbb R$

$\mathscr T =\{(a,+\infty)|a ∈ \Bbb R\} ∪ \{\Bbb R\}  ∪ \{\emptyset\}$
is a topology i.e. a runs over all real numbers, i.e. for every a we have $(a,+\infty) \in \mathscr T $.

Show that $( \Bbb R, \mathscr T )$ is not a Hausdorff topological space

So I think I should be basing my answer for first part like part c from [Prove that the following collection of subsets of $\Bbb R$ is a topology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477217/prove-that-the-following-collection-of-subsets-of-bbb-r-is-a-topology?rq=1) but i'm not really sure, can anyone give any hints to help?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a Mathjax tutorial.  Enclose mathematical expressions in $s

Comment: See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a tutorial on how to use MathJax to typeset mathematical formulas.

Comment: thank you, I think I have finally figured MathJax out now!

Comment: Though my curly brackets {} wont stay around my subsets...?

Comment: @bluekat16 use an escape key : example `$\{1,2,3,4\}$` renders $\{1,2,3,4\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let  $\mathscr T =\{(a,+∞)|a ∈ \Bbb R \} ∪ \{\Bbb R\}∪\{\emptyset\}$

1. $\emptyset$, $\Bbb R \in \mathscr T$ by definition
2. Let $\{S_i\}_{i \in I}$ with $S_i \in \mathscr T$. If $\exists i \ $ s.t. $S_i=\Bbb R$ then $\cup_{i \in I}S_i=\Bbb R \in \mathscr T$. If $S_i\neq \Bbb R \  \forall i$ then $S_i=(a_i, +\infty)$ and so $\cup_{i \in I}S_i= (\inf a_i, +\infty) \in \mathscr T$ ($\inf$ can be $-\infty$
3. Let $S_1, S_2 \in \mathscr T$. If $S_i=\mathbb R$ or  $S_i=\emptyset$ $S_1 \cap S_2 \in \mathscr T$ trivially. Else $S_i=(a_i, +\infty)$ and $S_1 \cap S_2=(\max a_i,+\infty) \in \mathscr T$

$\mathscr T$ is not $T_2$: let $x,y\in \Bbb R$ s.t. $x < y$. Let $A \in \mathscr T$ an open not empty set s.t. $x\in A$. If $A= \Bbb R$ then $y \in A$ if $A=(a, +\infty)$ then $y\in A$. So you can't find $A,B$ disjoint open neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$